# How to use PowMod correcly?

Tags: math

If you have to implement the following computation:

[image]

What is the correct way to implement it?

```
b^-c * powmod(g,s_3, p)
```

or

```
(b^-c * powmod(g,s_3, p)) % p
```

or

```
powmod(b,-c,p) * powmod(g,s_3, p)
```

or

```
(powmod(b,-c,p) * powmod(g,s_3, p)) % p
```

Comment: (a*b)%c = ((a%c)*(b%c))%c

Comment: Can your `powmod` handle negative exponents?

Comment: @LutzL aw I didn't even think about that. It seems that it can't

Comment: It's trivial to handle negative exponents

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `% p` in the end is of course required, otherwise you could get a result much larger than `p`.

`b^-c` is extremely incorrect in this context, since it has no way to know that it's a modular exponentiation and unlike positive exponents that isn't just a performance issue but a correctness issue as well: a normal negative exponent gives a fractional result, which is meaningless here.

By elimination that leaves only your last suggestion:

`(powmod(b,-c,p) * powmod(g,s_3, p)) % p`

Answer (score 1):

```
( a * b ) % c = (( a % c )*( b % c )) % c
```

So,

```
(b^-c * g^s_3)) % p = ((b^-c % p)*(g^s_3 % p)) % p
```

`g^s_3 % p` and `b^-c % p` should be solved using `powmod`. The correct implementation of powmod is upto you.

[How to deal with negative exponents in modular arithmetic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1015713/how-to-deal-with-negative-exponents-in-modular-arithmetic) might help you.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on if `powmod` can handle negative exponents, the last one is correct. The first two have the non-interpretable `b^-c` (or it is interpreted as `XOR` operation on the bit sequences), the third one might have result larger than `p` as a product of two remainders mod `p` can be as large as `(p-1)^2`.

To get the negative exponents right, use the little theorem of Fermat:

> for any prime `p` and `a%p!=0` one has `a^(p-1)%p==1`.

so that the complete computation is

```
(powmod(b, p-1-(c%(p-1)),p) * powmod(g,s_3,p) ) % p
```